# How to write .graph file

Tags: android, sql, graphql

I am new to GraphQL so please sorry if it is a stupid question but, how do I know how to write a `.graphql` file ? I refer at the content of the files:

[image]

I have the schema.json, but I don't know how exactly to compose my `.graphql` files, is there any tutorial on how to structure your query?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

`.graphql` file stores GraphQL independent query, because GraphQL syntax have import or similar construction. So you don't have ability to compose your queries from the box. As workaround you can use approach similar to [prisma graphql-import](https://oss.prisma.io/content/graphql-import/overview). But it related to GraphQL server based on JS. I don't know a tool for client and android.

My recommendation is don't worry about query duplication right now. Create new query at [**graphiql**](https://github.com/graphql/graphiql) or similar tool and put them to new `.graphql`. When you will have experience with GraphQL you can find your approach for composing queries.